# Best order for sharding and indexing

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a lot of data that is going into a sharded cluster.

What order should insert, index and shard ?

Would it be best to

1) bulk insert data > shard > index

or

2) bulk insert data > index > shard

or

3) shard > bulk insert data > index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely create indexes and then shard your collection **before** you insert the documents.

You should consider [pre-spliting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/) the chunk ranges before you insert the data for high write throughput. In most cases this will also expedite the distribution of data between shards. Take a look also at the [chunk migration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/migrate-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/).

Answer (score 0):

If you can have your inserted data pre-sorted, I would go with #3.
Decide about sharding, then load docs in parallel.